work-up with trialkyl aluminum reagent
I am doing some organic chemistry with triethylaluminum.  When the rxn is done, I do a simple alcohol/water quench (stoichiometric amount of water, xs ethanol - to keep this a 1 phase system for waste management purposes).  After this I would like to filter off the alumina/aluminum hydroxide, but it is very fine and clogs a coarse glass frit and routine paper filter.
Are there any tricks to expedite the aluminum material converting to insoluble (or at least easily filtered) alumina?  Excess water isn't an option.  Solid acid (NH4Cl)?  solid base?  Flocculent?
Thanks.

Try filtering it through a pad of Celite https://www.sigmaaldrich.com/GB/en/product/sigald/06858
If that doesn't work you could try altering your work-up to dropwise addition of strong NaOH which works very well for LiAlH4 reaction mixtures. See this example

I had success filtered the Al(OH)3/Al2O3 with the following changes (based on the above suggestions - thank you!).
